# Invalid Qualifier - When trying to Fire Checkbox click

Tags: excel, vba

I assigned a macro to my checkbox, so that when you tick it, it sets a certain value into a cell. I however get a `invalid qualifier` error on my first `Checkbox1`.value.

Here's the code:

```
Option Explicit

Public CheckBox1 As Boolean

Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then Range("Q10").Value = 1
If CheckBox1.Value = False Then Range("Q10").Value = 0

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have used an ActiveX control with the name CheckBox1, if so you are having the problem because you've also defined the public boolean CheckBox1.

You're code is unhappy since the public declaration of the CheckBox1 boolean is overwriting the control variable CheckBox1 and a `boolean` doesn't have a `.Value` property.  If you want to store the use of the checkbox value in a boolean then change your public variable name from Checkbox1, otherwise delete this declaration entirely.

Edit:
Based on your comment, you are not linking the checkbox from your worksheet.  The code has to know what CheckBox1.  Since you've deleted the boolean it now does not know what `Checkbox1` is.  Consequently you need to tell it where the checkbox is.
You can do it a number of ways.  If it is a form checkbox (not ActiveX like I first thought) then the following code will work:

```
Sub Checkbox1()
    Dim cb As Object, myCheckBoxValue As Boolean

    'Get the object from the worksheet
    Set cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object

    'Assign it's value to the boolean (1 is checked, -4146 is unchecked, 2 is mixed (grey box))
    If cb.Value = 1 Then myCheckBoxValue = True Else myCheckBoxValue = False

    'Output to worksheet
    If myCheckBoxValue Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q10").Value = 1
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q10").Value = 0
    End If
    Set cb = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can also cut this down significantly and the following will work:

```
Sub Checkbox1()
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q10").Value = 1
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("Q10").Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Ach I am so frustrated, I deleted this command and I get this error now: `Object Required`. Specifically, this `If CheckBox1.Value = True Then`. I even deleted the old checkbox and made a new one with the assigned code, to no avail.

Comment: hey @pufAmuf, I've expanded my answer to help you.